# Snowflake permission issue for "GRANT USAGE ON FUTURE PROCEDURES IN SCHEMA MyDb.MySchema TO ROLE MyRole"

Tags: permissions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to grant usage on future stored procedures within a particular schema.

I am using the role SYSADMIN and the schema is owned by SYSADMIN.

The following statement works

```
GRANT USAGE ON ALL PROCEDURES IN SCHEMA UAT_CONTROL.PDS TO ROLE UAT_OPERATIONS;
```

While this one fails

```
GRANT USAGE ON FUTURE PROCEDURES IN SCHEMA UAT_CONTROL.PDS TO ROLE UAT_OPERATIONS;
```

> "SQL Error [3001] [42501]: SQL access control error: Insufficient
> privileges to operate on schema 'PDS'

Am I missing a trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to provide the answer in case someone was looking for it in this forum.  The MANAGE GRANTS privilege is required for future grants:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-configure.html#security-privileges-required-to-manage-future-grants

Answer (score 0):

You also have to grant usage on your database and maybe on your schema:

```
GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE UAT_CONTROL TO ROLE UAT_OPERATIONS;

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA PDS TO ROLE UAT_OPERATIONS;
```

More infos here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege.html

Comment: For some reason that I do not fully understand yet, I have to use the SECURITYADMIN role for it to work. I thought SYSADMIN being the owner of the database it should work but this is not the case.
With SECURITYADMIN it works

Comment: @EricMamet by default only ACCOUNTADMIN and SECURITYADMIN can issue GRANTS. Generally SYSADMIN has systemwide access to all objects, except for USER and ROLE objects.

Comment: I was able to assign other GRANTS as SYSADMIN. It's only the "future" GRANTS that failed...?